# How to fix Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly Error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I get many errors like this:`Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in the following modules:...`

This is an indication that i miss an exclude, but i have the following lines in my build.gtadle

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' , module:'kotlin-stdlib'
    compile.exclude group: 'com.intellij', module:'annotations'
}
```

So what is missing?

Edit:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    
    //Firebase
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    //Graphview
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    //Google Play
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0"
    //FirebaseUI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    //Support
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.13"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    /**
     * dependency to request the runtime permissions.
     */
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

    // code generator for view
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

So here are my dependencies, i have this packages not directly included, but somehow they are i guess indirectly.

This seems to be to much code for the post so i have to add some text

Comment: Can you post your dependencies?

Comment: Added...hope this helps

Comment: Can you use gradle dependencies to check the dependency tree?

Comment: I tried it, now i got the following error `Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'` from your dependencies it is known to cause duplicate class errors.

You can also use implementation `'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'`